# PHP: How to get Day using Y-m-d?

Tags: php, date

I am trying to get Day(Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday,...) using "Y-m-d" date format but it is not giving me exact day.

For example:

```
date("l","2014-07-26"); // Output: Thursday
```

But output should be: Saturday

Thanks

Comment: Just to add to this: strtotime() does seem to correctly support dates beyond 2038 (like many Unix apps) but DateTime() does. Obviously still tempting to use strtotime() for one liners (and will likely be patched closer to the time) but if possibly calculating anything based on long term metrics it's something to mindful of.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Or with [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object

```
$dt = new DateTime('2014-07-26');
echo $dt->format('l'); // Saturday
```

or with the procedural aliases

```
echo date_format(date_create('2014-07-26'), 'l');
```

Comment: Oh that's much better than my (and everyone elses) strtotime() solution. Shame on me for not suggesting the DateTime() class.

Comment: @Iain it's an alternative. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: In the case of PHP I actually think it's worth advocating newer OO interfaces because the naming conventions and argument order of older built-in methods is so inconsistent. Not that I consistently practice what I'm preaching here. *ahem*

Comment: @Iain Collins: For what it's worth, the DateTime constructor actually uses strtotime.  When you're just doing date formatting, DateTime can be a bit overkill, even though it's totally awesome.  Remember: Always try to use the most simple solution that might work.

Comment: @Charles I agree that strtotime() works in this example; but disagree the 'most simple solution that might work' is what PHP developers, specifically, need to be doing more of. There are some very compelling reasons to get into the habit of using DateTime class (timezone handling, support for wider date ranges, exception handling and extension, anytime you need to do additional date+time manipulation). Bit of a general OOP vs procedural debate though.

Comment: @Iain, it's also a development methodology debate.  My team latched on to "the most simple thing that could possibly work" as an argument against our old lead dev's tendency towards over-engineering entire systems.  We've since extended the semi-philosophy to a mantra to make sure we don't fall into the same trap.  DateTime is indeed awesome, and we're using it throughout our new projects exclusively.  But sometimes, sometimes you just need something simple and stupid.  :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use mktime(), as others have suggested but strtotime() is a bit more flexible and user friendly.

```
date('l', strtotime('2014-07-26'));
```

Comment: Actually Gordon's suggestion of using the DateTime class is probably a better idea (unless it's really more appropriate to stick to a one liner).

Answer (score 3):

date() takes a unix timestamp as it's second parameter, not a string representation of a date. If you want to do that, you should convert to a unixtimestamp first using strtotime()

Answer (score 2):

a very easy way is to use [strtotime](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php):

```
date("l",strtotime("2014-07-26"));
```

Answer (score 1):

php date function accepts a format and a timestamp.  Using "2014-07-26" as a timestamp is not correct.  You should be using unix epoch timestamp.

TO do this you could for example do:

```
$t = "2014-07-26"; 
$t = explode("-", $t); //not $t = array("2014", "07", "26"); 
echo date("1", mktime(0,0,0,$t[1], $t[2], $t[0]); //using mktime with 
                                                  //hour, min, sec, month, day, year
```

Answer (score 1):

The second arg needs to be a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to use mktime to convert the date to a timestamp first

```
date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 7, 26, 2014));
```

[date](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php)
[mktime](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php)